# Error:Abnormal build process termination: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, javascript, android, git

I started `Android Studio` in my newly updated OS X (Mavericks now).

Now in Android Studio (also just updated btw) I get a message `"error running git"`

> Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.initLoggers(BuildMain.java:339)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.(BuildMain.java:67)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:58)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have:

- **Two different** versions of **log4j** included in your project
- Your **log4j.jar** file is **duplicated**.

The first is more likely
Hope it works ;-)